# Laravel 5.1 php.ini upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, laravel-5

I've got an application using Laravel 5.1 which uploads files to the server. The server has a restriction of 8M on file uploads which is too low. Where in the Laravel file structure should a php.ini file be placed to overwrite this?

I've put it in public and receive the following:
`Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/foldername/public_html/solutionfolder/config/database.php on line 16`

If I put it anywhere else, such as the root directory it is ignored.

I've looked at editing the .htacess file but that isn't working either.

Comment: If you are using heroku, you can update the file size limit by adding a user.ini file in `public/`

PHP will read settings from any .user.ini file in the same directory as the .php file that is being served. PHP will also read settings from a .user.ini file in any parent directory up to your application’s configured document root.

See this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#php-runtime-settings

Answer (score 1):

Please check your appache config.
Is it set AllowOverride = All ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the dafault settings by setting your new values in .htaccess.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

Comment: try stopping and starting the server. You can try composer dump also to see if it works

Comment: try changing  `post_max_size`. it can also cause issues. `php_value post_max_size 20M`

Comment: No dice unfortunately, seems to be ignoring everything. I wonder if it has anything to do with artisan running the app from cli. Perhaps it is constantly defaulting.

Comment: Try php --ini at the terminal to see the loaded php.ini file.